# How to make a background transparent without affecting child elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, transparent

Say if I have:

```
<Grid Background="LightGray" Margin="2,4,2,4" Opacity="0.5">
<Image Source="{Binding FullName}" Width="300" Height="170" />
</Grid>
```

This will also make the Image have an Opacity of 0.5. Is it possible to have the background transparent while the Image remains with an Opacity of 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify your own `Brush` object with an alpha channel (opacity) component that is not 1.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
       <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF295564" Opacity="0.3"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

It is worth noting that the first byte of the color's hex value is the alpha transparency but the Opacity property lets you use a double, not an unsigned byte. It is slightly easier to read.

Comment: I think if you're going to use this approach you should drop off the alpha channel from the hex colour used (making `#295564`), to avoid any confusion. Not required, but helpful.

Comment: @DanielMay you're probably right. I wasn't aware it was valid to omit it!

Comment: Yep!! It'll infer it's `FF` (100%) by default. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the opacity in the brush used for the `Grid`'s `Background` property rather than applying the opacity to the entire Grid element..

WPF's `LightGray` is `#FFD3D3D3` - so you could use `#80D3D3D3`.

Answer (score 1):

Background can take a color in hex format as well:

```
a is alpha
r is red
g is green
b is blue
```

Possible formats ([from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
<object property="predefinedBrushName"/>
- or -
<object property="#rgb"/>
- or -
<object property="#argb"/>
- or -
<object property="#rrggbb"/>
- or -
<object property="#aarrggbb"/>
- or -
<object property="sc#scA,scR,scG,scB"/>
- or -
<object property="ContextColor profileUri alphaValue,colorValue"/>
```

So we can use `Background="#80D3D3D3"` (([LightGray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.lightgray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined as `#FFD3D3D3` so I changed the opacity to 50%)

```
<Grid Background="#80D3D3D3" Margin="2,4,2,4">
    <Image Source="{Binding FullName}" Width="300" Height="170" />
</Grid>
```